# PhpStorm "keep memory changes" by default?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, conflict

Often PhpStorm throw a file conflict and ask me if keep file or memory changes.

This could be why I keep the files I am working on in OneDrive, and when I save them OneDrive upload them, so maybe "mark" them as uploaded and PhpStorm throw a conflict...

How can I set by default "keep memory changes" option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do this, please vote for [IDEA-132733](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132733)

Comment: Why this appen (the file conflict) ?

Comment: when the file is changed externally and in PHPStorm

Comment: But I do not change the file... could be OneDrive auto-upload?

Comment: @Francesco There are a wide variety of apps that could cause this behavior.  I am fighting with it now because the "fsnotify" plugin for Vagrant is doing a `touch` on a file opened in PHPStorm so the "File Cache Conflict" prompt is coming up all of the time.